# Wipe data on device completely

Tags: applications, nexus-7, data-recovery

I have a nexus 7 1st gen, which has a cracked screen.
I am planning to repair and got a quote from a local store.
But, before handing over the device to them, I would like to clear my data on the device.
I heard that the data can be recovered even after a factory reset.

Is there an application or a way to remove the data completely, just like zero-fill, so that the data wiped / removed cannot be recovered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way is to go into Security -> Encryption. Encrypt your phone, which takes several hours. Then do a factory reset.

Others will have no way of recovering your personal data.

**Additional Info**:

It works much like BitLocker on Windows. When you start up the phone, you'll be required to enter a password before loading Android OS (or the Recovery Mode). Afterwards, none of the applications running on the OS will even notice the encryption.

What the encryption does is:
1) make it extremely difficult (i.e. for all practical purposes impossible) for other software to recover the /sdcard/ files (e.g. user data) after a factory reset.
2) prevent external applications and operating systems from reading those files without first decrypting it, which requires Android OS to load.

Comment: Will encrypting the data on device, encrypt data in cloud? Can I sync my data from cloud later without encryption?

Comment: It works much like BitLocker on Windows. None of the applications running on the OS will notice the encryption.

Comment: Other [sites](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-wipe-android-phone-or-tablet/) suggest to fill dummy data, even after a factory reset with encrypted data. And there is an application [Secure Erase with iShredder 3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projectstar.ishredder.android.standard)